# Checkbox value not being returned on checkbox change

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, addeventlistener, onchange

I am creating checkboxes from an array of objects. `on change`, I am not getting back anything.

My code:

```js
let res = [
  { id: "123", fullName: "harry potter", username: "harrypotter" },
  { id: "345", fullName: "hermione granger", username: "hermionegranger" },
  { id: "678", fullName: "ron weasley", username: "ronweasley" },
  { id: "789", fullName: "ginny weasley", username: "ginnyweasley" },
  { id: "987", fullName: "luna lovegood", username: "lunalovegood" },
];

let cbs = document.getElementById("cboxes");
for (const cb of res) {
        cbs.innerHTML += `<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="${cb.username}" name="${cb.username}" value="${cb.id}">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="${cb.username}">${cb.username}</label>
        </div>`;
        
let chck = document.getElementById(cb.username);
chck.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
   if (event.currentTarget.checked) {
       alert(`checked ${this.value}`);
   } else {
       alert("not checked");
   }
 });
}
```

```html
<div id="cboxes"></div>
```

On checkbox check I want the checkbox value returned. My code is returning nothing.

Comment: event.target.value. There is no `this` available unless you use the function keyword (or bind, but that is unnecessary here)

Comment: I strongly suggest to delegate. Move this outside the loop: `cbs.addEventListener("change", (event) => { const tgt = event.currentTarget; const txt = tgt.checked ? \`checked ${tgt.value}\` : "not checked"; alert(txt)
 });`

Comment: I have the feeling the 'this question has an answer here' alternative is not the right one, or at least not completely. From what I can see, only the last checkbox reacts, due to the way the html is added: the innerHtml is changed, the objects are rendered, change is assigned, then in the next iteration, innerHtml is overwritten, creating new elements, which causes the previous assigned change never to fire (element being a new one) Regardless, several work arounds, for example, using onchange directly: https://jsfiddle.net/wns28hu7/

Comment: @Me.Name, thanks! This worked!